# What does "get some foxes in this here town" mean?

Tags: meaning

> ...get some foxes in this here town.

Is "get some foxes" an idiomatic expression with an implied meaning?

It's quite weird and awkward to see such phrase as "in this here town"; I myself can't understand it in any grammatical way. How shall I understand it? Is it an informal usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Foxes" is (out of date) slang for attractive women.

"This here XXX" means the same as "this town". This form of speech is probably being used to signify the speaker is from a rural area of America and not highly educated. "This here" is often associated with cowboys and the "old west", but could also be found in other contexts.

Comment: Thank you. So does "you sure enough got some foxes in this here town" mean "you must have landed some sexy girls in this town"? Or, does it mean "there must be some attractive women in your town"?

Comment: Probably it means "your town has some attractive women". Assuming the person being spoken to lives in the town and the speaker is from somewhere else. It would be easier to be sure what's meant with more context.

Comment: The phrase "You sure do XXXX" or "You sure enough do XXX" is usually uttered when the speaker has just seen evidence that XXXX is true.  So the speaker probably just saw several attractive women walk by, and then said, "You sure enough got [do have] some ..."

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing to suggest “landing some sexy girls”, no act is implied, it refers to there being some good looking ladies in this here town. This here, as pointed before, suggests lack of formal education or rural background but can also be used in jest or the speaker is mocking the authority of the person he’s talking to and making himself look lower in social standing while not actually believing it. Not in the case above, though.